# How to load .rds R file as a Spark dataframe in Scala

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a production data pipeline for a model . As a part of this pipeline, I save a model which runs in `R` environment as `.rds` file. Here is an example -

```
set.seed(345)

df = data.frame(x = rnorm(20))

df = transform(df , y = 5 + (2.3*x) + rnorm(20))

## model
m1 = lm(y ~ x , data = df)

## Take out the coefficients 
coeff = m1$coefficients

> coeff
(Intercept)           x 
   4.938554    2.328345

## save the model coefficients
saveRDS(coeff, "~/Desktop/coeff.rds")
```

Now, I would like to somehow load these `coefficients` in a Scala program as a `Spark Dataframe`, which might look something like this -

```
val loadCoefficients = # some method to load .rds file as a Spark Data frame
```

Is there any library that can allow me to achieve this? My end result in Spark context should look like -

```
loadCoefficients.show
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
(Intercept)           x 
   4.938554    2.328345
```

Comment: Did you find the resolution for this?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

check this which might help sparkR the author is doing pretty close to what you are trying,sparkR is a shell which comes with Spark distribution by default, hope this helps.

https://cosminsanda.com/posts/a-compelling-case-for-sparkr/

also check this function in SparkR which can convert R data frame to spark data frame if you can convert coeff value to R dataframe then you can easily convert to spark dataframe.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/R/createDataFrame.html